# Combining styles conditionally in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'd like to use a 3rd party lib like [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) but for React Native. I have a `Text` component and a styles.js object that has multiple styles. What is the best way to create a base style and then other styles that are conditionally passed to my `Text` component if props are true/false?

Here is my styles.js

```js
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { tokens } from "../../tokens/tokens";

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {},
  // color styles
  textColorPrimary: {
    color: tokens.themeColorForegroundPrimary,
  },
  textColorNeutralHigh: {
    color: tokens.themeColorForegroundNeutralHigh,
  },
  textColorOnPrimary: {
    color: tokens.themeColorForegroundOnPrimary,
  },
  textColorOnSecondary: {
    color: tokens.themeColorForegroundOnSecondary,
  },
  // size styles
  textSizeSmall: {
    fontSize: 14,
    lineHeight: 20,
  },
  textSizeMedium: {
    fontSize: 16,
    lineHeight: 22,
  },
  textSizeLarge: {
    fontSize: 32,
    lineHeight: 24,
  },

  // weight styles
  textWeight400: {
    fontWeight: 400,
  },
  textWeight700: {
    fontWeight: 700,
  },
});
```

and here is my Text.tsx

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { Text as NativeText } from "react-native";
import { styles } from "./TextStyles";

export interface TextProps {
  color?:
    | "neutralHigh"
    | "neutralMedium"
    | "primary"
    | "onPrimary"
    | "onSecondary";
  weight?: 400 | 700;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  size?: "small" | "medium" | "large";
}

export const Text: React.FC<TextProps> = ({
  color = "neutralHigh",
  weight = 400,
  children,
  size = "medium",
  ...props
}) => {
  let textColorStyle = {};
  let textSizeStyle = {};
  let textWeightStyle = { fontWeight: 700 };

  switch (color) {
    case "primary":
      textColorStyle = styles.textColorPrimary;
      break;
    case "neutralHigh":
      textColorStyle = styles.textColorNeutralHigh;
      break;
  }

  switch (size) {
    case "small":
      textSizeStyle = styles.textSizeSmall;
      break;
    case "medium":
      textSizeStyle = styles.textSizeMedium;
      break;
    case "large":
      textSizeStyle = styles.textSizeLarge;
      break;
  }

  switch (weight) {
  }

  return (
    <NativeText
      {...props}
      style={[styles.text, textColorStyle, textSizeStyle, textWeightStyle]}
    >
      {children}
    </NativeText>
  );
};
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419909/is-a-question-asking-for-good-ways-to-do-something-really-opinion-based